# Parsing the end of a tcp connection

Tags: sockets, tcp

There are a number of ways that a TCP connection can end.  This is my understanding:

`rst`: is immediate.  The connection is done, and immediately closes.  All further communication is a "new" connection.

`fin`: is a nice request from one side.  It must be `ack`nowledged, and the other side then sends a `fin` to say they are done talking.  This too must be `ack`nowledged.  These stages CAN happen simultaneously, but a `fin` and the `ack` that accompanies it must be passed.

Are there any others?  I'm looking at a tcp stream in Wireshark that just has a `fin`, `psh`, and `ack` bit sent.  This is acknowledged and the connection is over.  What other ways of closing a TCP connection are there?

If a `fin` is `ack`ed, can more data be sent?  If it is, does the original `fin` need to be resent (does the state of the side that sent the `fin` reset at some point)?

Comment: https://www.google.hu/search?q=tcp+state+diagram&tbm=isch

Comment: Kindly read the question before leaving pointless google searches.  There are more ways to end the connection than that diagram (most of those don't even mention reset!), and the common way of ending a connection is the second point I mention.  I'm interested in non-standard ways that connections die.

Comment: Assuming there is one, which is what a state diagram should show. The *real* TCP state diagram in RFC 793 shows clearly that there isn't any other way to terminate a TCP connection.

Comment: @EJP:  There are other ways that TCP connections die however.  Computers fall off networks (when you put your computer to sleep, it doesn't necessarily kill all open connections).  These are timeout events.  Is there a process for ending a connection via timeout?  (I.E. I send a "are you there" packet a few times over a few minutes, and when I get no response, I shut down the connection, sending resets if you finally show up)  Is that standard?

Comment: @AndrewScott These are ways that *networks* die. Your question is about TCP connections. Every one of the conditions you mention will produce either a reset or an application timeout. Period.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any others?

No.

> I'm looking at a tcp stream in Wireshark that just has a fin, psh, and ack bit sent. This is acknowledged and the connection is over.

No. It is shut down in one direction only. It isn't over until both peers have sent a FIN.

> What other ways of closing a TCP connection are there?

None.

> If a fin is acked, can more data be sent?

It can't be sent even if the FIN wasn't ACKed, in the direction that the FIN was sent. It can be sent in the other direction.

> If it is, does the original fin need to be resent (does the state of the side that sent the fin reset at some point)?

Can't happen.

Comment: This is correct, but it is possible that a TCP/IP stack doesn't abide by the [RFC](http://ietf.org/rfc/rfc793).  Some vendors are notorious for this.

Comment: What about timeouts or dropped connections?  Is there any sort of standard way of dealing with them?

Comment: @AndrewSpott normally you heartbeat a TCP connection when it needs to persist (e.g. send a small packet periodically).

Comment: @Jason:  And how do you tear down a connection when the heartbeat fails (isn't acknowledged)

Comment: @AndrewSpott A TCP keepalive failure will produce a reset. If it's your own timeout, or heartbeat implemented in your application protocol, you will just close the socket, which sends a FIN etc.

Comment: @AndrewSpott You'll generally get an `RST` if the other side is closed.  The TCP/IP stack might send a `FIN` back on closing the socket.

Comment: @Jason the most common scenario for a RST is when you send a packet to a server where nobody is listening on the port to which it was sent. This because there was never ever someone listening on that port, or because the server rebooted.

Comment: @Jason Or because the peer application timed out or gave up for some other reason.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck Yes but when a server reboots it *shouldn't* leave the socket half open, the application should close the socket.  The `RST` is a way of dealing with the inconsistent state.  An `RST` could be sent in response to a `SYN` as well though.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed only 2 ways to close a TCP connection.

- The FIN 4 way handshake
- The RST

The FIN mechanism is the normal way of closing a TCP connection. You must understand that a TCP socket has a state machine underneeth. This statemachine is checked for each operation on the socket that happens. A close on a socket is called a halfclose. If you do this, it is like telling I have nothing more to send anymore. The state machine underneeth the socket is really going to check this, if you still were to try to send you will get error return codes.
The statemachine i am talking about is very well described over here with drawings ;-) http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPOperationalOverviewandtheTCPFiniteStateMachineF-2.htm

The TCP/IP guide is an online book, also the RST scenario's that can happen are described in that book, as is the sliding window mechanism, byte acking, nagle and many other things. And not just for TCP, other protocols as well.